# HTTP Post in angular 2 with laravel 5.3 backend

Tags: php, laravel, angular

I have two tables (College Table and High School Table) with same attributes. What i want to do is send data from  College Table to High School Table. For instance, I have Datmor College in College Table, if i press on a button with a function called sendtoHighSchool(), Datmor College should be posted to High School Table.

When i click on the "send to high school" button, i see the the data has been fetched alright but i still get this error

```
" POST http://localhost:3000/api/college_api/v1/colleges 500 (Internal Server Error)
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error for URL: http://localhost:3000/api/college_api/v1/colleges 
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵    <head>↵        <meta ch…l>↵</div>↵↵            </div>↵    </body>↵</html>", status: 500, ok: false, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers…}
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:227
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335"
```

//Table

```
<td><a class="btn btn-success" (click)="addToHighSchool()"><em class="fa fa-plus"></em></a>Send to High school</td>
```

//College Component

```
addToHighSchool(college) {
    this.httpService.add(college)
    .subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data)
    });
    console.log(college)
}
```

//service

```
add(user:any) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(user);
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/college_api/v1/colleges', body, {headers: headers})
    .map((data:Response) => data.json());
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the CSRF token, read more https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf

Comment: @ka_lin, thanks but i have already done that. All other methods (delete, get) . I have another function which is also performing post function and works fine but the above fails

Comment: Have you read any errors in the log? It seems to be a server-side issue

Comment: Okay.. I will work and the server side and get back at you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php find this and write protected

`$except = [
   'api/*'
];`

then find routes and modify

`<?php
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function(){
    Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController', ['except' => [
        'create', 'edit'
    ]]);
});`